# Appending data to a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

The error I am getting is a write() takes exactly one argument (5 given). I was able to get the write to work by making a write statement on each line, but that caused each of the inputs to be written on a new line. What I am trying to do is to have the write happen in a format similar to the table created for the temp file. I am not sure how I would implement the logic to make that happen.

```
import os
def main ():
    temp_file = open('temp.txt', 'a')
    temp_file.write('Product Code | Description | Price' + '\n'
    'TBL100 | Oak Table | 799.99' + '\n'
    'CH23| Cherry Captains Chair | 199.99' + '\n' 
    'TBL103| WalnutTable |1999.00' + '\n'
    'CA5| Chest Five Drawer| 639' + '\n')

    another = 'y'
    # Add records to the file.
    while another == 'y' or another == 'Y':

        # Get the coffee record data.
        print('Enter the following furniture data:')
        code = input('Product code: ')
        descr = input('Description: ')
        price = float(input('Price: '))

        # Append the data to the file.
        temp_file.write(code, print('|'), descr, print('|'), str(price) + '\n')

        # Determine whether the user wants to add
        # another record to the file.
        print('Do you want to add another record?')
        another = input('Y = yes, anything else = no: ')

        # Close the file.
        temp_file.close()
        print('Data appended to temp_file.')
```

Comment: You can't just use `print` inside `write` itself, just build a string with all the elements, just use a '+' like at the begnning

Comment: You probably want to close your file after the loop, not inside it.

Comment: @khelwood thank you, I made that adjustment, I am guessing this would most likely be because certain parameters could cause an error when closing the file in the loop? I ran into that problem while trying to append multiple entries to the file. Closing outside the loop fixed that right up. Still learning all the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, just replace this line

```
temp_file.write(code, print('|'), descr, print('|'), str(price) + '\n')
```

by this line

```
temp_file.write(code + '|' + descr + '|' + str(price) + '\n')
```

> **Explanations:** 
>   The method `write` takes one argument, but you provide five in your code. That is the reason of the error you have got. You just have to concatenate your variables to get one string that you will pass to the method.

Answer (score 1):

You should only write one line via one parameter

```
temp_file.write(f'{code} | {descr} | {price}\n')
```